# How to uploadArchives with multiple repositories using parameters in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, build.gradle

In my gradle project, I want to upload my jar to multiple maven repository, so I do the following:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: maven_repo_1) {
                authentication(userName: maven_user_1, password: maven_password_1)
            }
            repository(url: maven_repo_2) {
                authentication(userName: maven_user_2, password: maven_password_2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is:

1. Is this the correct way to upload to multiple maven repository at once?
2. Is there a way to use a parameters to upload to specific maven repository? I.e `uploadArchives -r mavenLocal`

Note:
Previously I had to remove the maven repository and run `uploadArchives`, I don't think this is the best practice. However I didn't find documentation for uploading it with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is using a [project property](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-command-line-arguments) to pick the right configuration.

For example, if you want to deploy to a remote repository by default, but with a parameter that switches to a local repo:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        if (project.hasProperty('localRepoPath')) {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: uri(project.getProperty('localRepoPath')))
                ...
            }
        } else {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: maven_repo_1)
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to invoke:

```
# Local upload
./gradlew uploadArchives -PlocalRepoPath=/tmp/maven

# Public upload
./gradlew uploadArchives
```

You can adapt this approach to your own needs.